# ACF + Qtranslate-x (WP-4.8.1)

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, multilingual, qtranslate

I am using ACF plugins fo Advanced Custom Fields(4.4.11) + Advanced Custom Fields PRO(5.5.11) + Advanced Custom Fields: qTranslate(1.7.23).

I am using qTranslate-X pluign(3.4.6.8) and it is workign perfectly for pages + CPTs.

I have created option page in which i have created WP editor which i want to enable multilanguagl.

I have enable language switcher tab on top of page from ACF qtranslate by add page name in:
    Display the LSB on the following pages

code for editor is:

```
add_settings_field(
    'footer_heading',
    'Footer Heading',
    'footer_heading_callback',
    __FILE__,
    'footer_section'
);


function footer_heading_callback()
{
    $options = get_option('plugin_options');
    $footer_heading = wpautop($options['footer_heading']);
    echo wp_editor(
        $footer_heading,
        'footer_heading',
        $settings = array(
            'textarea_rows' => 8,
            'textarea_name' => 'plugin_options[footer_heading]',
                'editor_class' => 'wp-editor-area'
        )
    );       
}
```

I have tried change editor_class but can not working.

I have tried different solution from google but not working in my case.

Can any one guide me how to make this editor multilanguage.

Comment: Newest version of qTranslate allows json config and css classes to be added to fields you want to enable the LSB at.